# How do I delete or undraw a image in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jpanel, graphics2d

I'm trying to animate a background in a JPanel, but after a few cycles the background starts to have this "smear" effect. I think it's because Java is constantly drawing over the previous image, but I can't seem to find a way to "Un-draw" the image.

Part of the Background class

```
public void setPosition(double x, double y) {

    this.x = (x * moveScale) % GamePanel.WIDTH; 
    this.y = (y * moveScale) % GamePanel.HEIGHT;

}

public void setVector(double dx, double dy) {

    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;

}

public void update() {

    x += dx % GamePanel.WIDTH;
    y += dy % GamePanel.HEIGHT;  

}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    g.drawImage(image, (int) x, (int) y, null);


    if (x < 0) {

        g.drawImage(image, (int) x + GamePanel.WIDTH, (int) y, null);

    }

    if (x > 0) {

        g.drawImage(image, (int) x - GamePanel.WIDTH, (int) y, null);

    }

}
```

Part of the Menu class where it gets called

```
public void update() {

    bg.update();

}

public void draw (Graphics2D g) {

    bg.draw(g);

    g.setColor(titleColor);
    g.setFont(titleFont);
    g.drawString("Save Squishy!", 80, 70);

    g.setFont(font);
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {

        if (i == currentChoice) {

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        } else {

            g.setColor(Color.RED);

        }

        g.drawString(options[i], 145, 140 + (i * 15));

    }

}
```

Works fine for the first cycle:

[image: Works fine for the first cycle]

Then starts to smear

[image: Then Starts to smear]

Comment: How are you getting the Graphics object? Usually it is obtained from within a `paintComponent `override, and you should be sure to call the `super.paintComponent(g);` within your override, first method call. Much better if you could create and post your [mcve] (please read the link).

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter I used `private Graphics2D g; ` and then I initialized it with `g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics(); `, I don't use paintComponent in my program. Would that be a better idea?

Comment: That gets you the image Graphics object, but you need the JPanel's current Graphics object to draw something that will display.

Comment: But again, please show us a decent [mcve] / [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can test your code ourselves. And yes, you should draw within the `paintComponent method.

Comment: TIP: Gif images are automatically animated when in an [`ImageIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html). Using GIFs can solve this problem.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter I've shortened the code to just the components for the Menu Screen: Heres the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xevp5h9e67nw7y0/AACIQokByFrA4EoCuNKxC8WVa?dl=0)

Comment: Please let's avoid posting code in links. It's against site rules, and it's in your best interest to make your question as easy to answer as possible.

Comment: Alot of my code is in seperate classes, though. I'm not sure how to condense them into one class.

Comment: if the current answer is adequate, then you don't need to do this. If not, then you'll want to create the code.

Comment: *"I've shortened the code.."* There is more to MCVE than just 'minimal'. The edits do **not** show a valid MCVE (which, BTW, might be 100 lines of code if all are actually needed to show the problem).

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you should use the `paintComponent(g)` method that you override from a container-class like `JPanel` instead of creating your own paint/draw method or using the graphical object obtained from an image. Like this, you avoid troubles with repainting, just call `repaint()` on the class that extends JPanel.

As mentioned in the comments, it is recommended to use the `paintComponent(g)` method. Start with something like this:

```
public class TestImage extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage bimg = null;

    public TestImage() {
        // initiate the class ...
        try {
            bimg = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Path/To/Image/image.jpg"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(bimg, 0, 0, null);
        // do other painting stuff with g
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Image test demo");
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setSize(600, 400);
        fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        fr.add(new TestImage());
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, what he says. 1+

Comment: So would I use `bg.paint(g)` in order to draw the image?

Comment: You should use a single class for the main painting process (I guess in your case it should be GamePanel) and then call repaint() on that class instance. You can‘t call paint(g), because you do not have a Graphic object g. For some references and demos, see the Java Tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html